# Java SimpleDateFormat change to different TimeZone

Tags: java, java-7, simpledateformat

We use `SimpleDateFormat userDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00")` in the function of my application, **haven't set time zone**.

And every time userDateFormat created, I use

```
System.out.println("userDateFormat timezone: " + ((SimpleDateFormat)userDateFormat).getTimeZone().toString());
```

to get the TimeZone info of the userDateFormat.

During the application running with different calls of the function(server no shutdown), we get different time zone info:

```
userDateFormat timezone: sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]

userDateFormat timezone: sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/Copenhagen",offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=133,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/Copenhagen,offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=3600000,startTimeMode=2,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=3600000,endTimeMode=2]]
```

I am wonder why the timezone was changed here in this single server.

And we have another SimpleDateFormat object that has setTimeZone to 'GMT'(only set once in all the project), but from the result, it seems use the timezone 'CET(UTC+1)'. Is there any server setting that will cause the jdk timezone mess?

Thanks.

Comment: Application timezone could be changed using TimeZone#setDefault. It's a good practice to always set TimeZone to each SimpleDateFormat explicitly before printing any values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As bsiamionau said, we have code that call TimeZone.setDefault, which change the default timezone.